# Contents of iOS app

Tags: c++, ios, encryption, compression

We are trying to reduce the size of our IOS app. We've stripped the symbols and set the optimisation level to fastest/smallest. When we archive it and look inside the zipped up package at the raw "unix executable file" there are huge swathes of zeroes inside it. Our executable is 10Mb and there are 2Mb of contiguous zeroes inside it. I understand that Apple then encrypt this file before compressing it into the final IPA/ZIP, so these zeroes don't get compressed.

So what could these zeroes be? We did checks - they don't appear to be empty C++ structures, e.g. `char buffer[1024]`, as allocating these makes the app no smaller.

Any ideas, or any idea how I could find out what goes where inside the executable file?

Comment: Consider asking this on the Apple Developer Forums, there are Apple engineers there that might have better insight into this. Also you have at least two free Technical Support Incidents available per account, use one of these to get specific help.